# Getting error while creating a secured proxy

Tags: web-services, cxf, apache-camel, ws-security, wsse

I am trying to configure WSS4JInInterceptor in my cxf endpoint through camel-config.xml

Below is my camel-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- START SNIPPET: e1 -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
       xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd">

  <!-- spring property placeholder, ignore resource not found as the file resource is for unit testing -->
  <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:incident.properties,file:target/custom.properties"
                                ignore-resource-not-found="true"/>

  <!-- bean that enriches the SOAP request -->
  <bean id="enrichBean" class="org.apache.camel.example.cxf.proxy.EnrichBean"/>

  <bean id="loggingOutInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor"/>
  <bean id="loggingInInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor"/>


    <bean id="wss4jInInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor"> 
                 <property name="properties"> 
                     <map> 
                         <entry key="action" value="UsernameToken Timestamp"/> 
                         <entry key="passwordType" value="PasswordDigest"/> 
                         <entry key="ws-security.is-bsp-compliant" value="false"/>
                         <entry key="passwordCallbackClass" value="org.apache.camel.example.cxf.proxy.UTPasswordCallback"/>
                     </map> 
                 </property> 
             </bean> 

  <!-- this is the CXF web service we use as the front end -->
  <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="versionService"
                   address="http://localhost:${proxy.port}/camel-example-cxf-proxy/webservices/versionAdapter"
                   endpointName="s:VersionHttpSoap11Endpoint"                  
                   serviceName="s:Version"
                   wsdlURL="etc/versionAdapter.wsdl"
                   xmlns:s="http://axisversion.sample">

    <cxf:inInterceptors>
            <ref bean="loggingInInterceptor"/>
            <ref bean="wss4jInInterceptor"/>
    </cxf:inInterceptors>
    <cxf:outInterceptors>
            <ref bean="loggingOutInterceptor"/>
    </cxf:outInterceptors>

  </cxf:cxfEndpoint>

  <!-- this is the Camel route which proxies the real web service and forwards SOAP requests to it -->
  <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

    <!-- property which contains port number -->
    <propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="classpath:incident.properties,file:target/custom.properties"/>

    <endpoint id="callRealWebService" uri="http://localhost:${real.port}/axis2/services/Version?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnFailure=false"/>

    <route>
      <!-- CXF consumer using MESSAGE format -->
      <from uri="cxf:bean:versionService?dataFormat=MESSAGE"/>
      <!-- log input received -->
      <to uri="log:input"/>
      <!-- enrich the input by ensure the incidentId parameter is set -->
      <to uri="bean:enrichBean"/>
      <!-- opp removing headers... testing -->
      <removeHeaders pattern="*" />
      <!-- send proxied request to real web service -->
      <to uri="callRealWebService"/>
      <!-- log answer from real web service -->
      <to uri="log:output"/>
    </route>

  </camelContext>

</beans>
<!-- END SNIPPET: e1 -->
```

When i invoke my proxy webservice i am getting error. Here is the complete error trace..

```
INFO: Inbound Message
----------------------------
ID: 1
Address: http://localhost:9080/camel-example-cxf-proxy/webservices/versionAdapter
Encoding: UTF-8
Http-Method: POST
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Headers: {accept-encoding=[gzip,deflate], connection=[keep-alive], Content-Length=[1097], content-type=[text/xml;charset
=UTF-8], Host=[localhost:9080], SOAPAction=["urn:getVersion"], User-Agent=[Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)]}
Payload: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:axis="http://axisversion.sample" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelop
e/">
   <soapenv:Header><wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-20
0401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utilit
y-1.0.xsd"><wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-42"><wsu:Created>2014-11-19T12:41:10Z</wsu:Created><wsu:Expires>2014-11-19T13:14:30
Z</wsu:Expires></wsu:Timestamp><wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-41"><wsse:Username>opp</wsse:Username><wsse:Pas
sword Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">m0c8nW1n+
/jfHzwM5lHc9F3+B1g=</wsse:Password><wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soa
p-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">VUr9FAuf1J/UYWEBMdTAlA==</wsse:Nonce><wsu:Created>2014-11-19T12:41:10.455Z</wsu:Cre
ated></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security></soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <axis:getVersion/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
--------------------------------------
Inside UTPasswordCallback Method @ UTPasswordCallback class
Wed Nov 19 18:10:33 IST 2014 Inside UTPasswordCallback()--> UTPasswordCallback Class
Nov 19, 2014 6:10:33 PM org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor checkActions
WARNING: Security processing failed (actions mismatch)
Nov 19, 2014 6:10:33 PM org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doDefaultLogging
WARNING: Interceptor for {http://axisversion.sample}Version has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: An error was discovered processing the <wsse:Security> header.
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.createSoapFault(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:809)
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:313)
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:93)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:243)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.doService(JettyHTTPDestination.java:261)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPHandler.handle(JettyHTTPHandler.java:70)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1088)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1024)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: An error was discovered processing the <wsse:Security> heade
r
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.checkActions(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:339)
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:297)
        ... 23 more
```

I am unable to figure out what this error is all about and how can i rectify this error?
Please help on this..

Comment: Which cxf version do you use?

Comment: i am using cxf version 3.0.1

Comment: Could you try to use at least cxf version 3.0.2, maybe it is this bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-5983

Comment: I tried with cxf version 3.0.2 but still i am getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

Please use CXF_MESSAGE data format instead of MESSAGE data format.

Comment: Hi Willem. Thanks for the help. I followed your suggestion and it worked. But now the problem is i am not able to get response out of camel. Axis service is returning the response but somehow camel is not showing it.

Comment: Did you get any thing from "log:output"?

Comment: Thanks for the reply willem..It actually worked when i USED PAYLOAD as my dataformat.